# ML in R (caret-package) missing hyperparameters

Tags: neural-network, r, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning

I have a pretty specific question regarding the **caret package** however I still hope to finde help here.

I recently worked with the caret package and trained a multilayer perceptron with `method = 'mlp'`. 
I looked up the [github page](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html#neural-network) of Max Kuhn (developer of caret), and it says that you only need to tune one hyperparameter: the size (number of neurons in the hidden layer). Which is really convinient.

However it further states that caret for the training builds on the **RSNNS Package** (by Bergmeier). The [mlp model](https://rdrr.io/cran/RSNNS/man/mlp.html) implemented in this RSNNS package has additional tunable parameters over just the size hyperparameter (i.e. learnFunc,hiddenActFunc,Std_Backpropagation, maxit).

So I asked myself what values caret uses for those parameters? Default values or are those optmizied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the defaults are used, except for `lin`, which is inferred from the type of the target variable: [[source code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/6546939345fe10649cefcbfee55d58fb682bc902/models/files/mlp.R#L16)]

Note too that you can set any of the other RSNNS parameters through the dots.

Comment: Thank you. Since I am not a Data Science expert would you recommend tuning another parameter like the Activation Function or # of iterarion. As Background we get around 90% Accuracy in a classification problem which is pretty reasonable for our field.

Comment: I guess that would be new questions?

Comment: @SysRIP, which hyperparameters to tune is certainly another question (probably already asked); but on topic here, I think that caret having deemed all the other defaults as good enough to not include as parameters indicates that `size` is a good enough start.  RSNNS indicates where you might go next, with "The defaults that are set for initialization and update functions usually don't have to be changed": that leaves activations, learning function, number of iterations.  RSNNS seems to be missing some modern options, e.g. RELU activation and adam optimizer?

Comment: Okay thanks a lot that was really helpfull. I wish I could gift you a upvote.